# Telerik SlideView for Windows Phone 7 smaller than 100 pixels (height)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, telerik, windows-phone

I'm using the Telerik SlideView inside my Windows Phone project to display two lines of text at a time. As this does not require a lot of space, I'd like to make the SlideView smaller than the 100 pixels which seem to be the minimum. Is that possible somehow? Simply setting the height does not change anything.

I know with the smaller target area, it would be harder for the user to swipe to the next content. However in this case this is not really an issue, as the content switches automatically.

Here's my current code:

```
<telerikPrimitives:RadSlideView x:Name="MetaSlideView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemRealizationMode="Default" Orientation="Horizontal" ManipulationCompleted="MetaSlideView_ManipulationCompleted" Height="34">
    <telerikPrimitives:RadSlideView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock x:Name="MetaLabel" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Label}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextAccentStyle}" Margin="0,0,12,0"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="MetaText" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerikPrimitives:RadSlideView.ItemTemplate>
</telerikPrimitives:RadSlideView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you just have to overwrite the set the minheight property.
http://www.telerik.com/forums/slideview-height-automatic-switching